# Integer modulo character (which is also a number) gives incorrect result

Tags: java, modulus

I've tried searching for an existing question that may already have an answer but could not find one.
For a given integer n, I am trying to apply modulo operator as:

```
n%(each digit of n)
```

I am converting the given integer "n" to String and then getting each digit of the given number using `str.charAt()` method.

```
static int findDigits(int n) {
        String num = String.valueOf(n);
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<num.length(); i++)
        {
            if(n % num.charAt(i) == 0)
            {

                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

But, `n % num.charAt(i)` is not returning the correct result.
For example, if n is 12: when i=0, 12%1 is returning 12 instead of 0.
If n is 1012: when i=0, 1012%1 is returning 32 instead of 0.

Converting num.charAt(i) to Integer i.e. `Integer.valueOf(num.charAt(i))` also does not work, it has no effect:

I found that using `Character.getNumericValue()` method gives the correct result.
Why?
This works:

```
static int findDigits(int n) {
            String num = String.valueOf(n);
            int count = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<num.length(); i++)
            {
                if(n % Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i)) == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: This `if(n % num.charAt(i) == 0)` is not doing what you think it's doing. the char that comes back is not the number that you think that it is, but rather the ascii value of the char.

Comment: Instead consider `if (n % Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))) == 0)`

Comment: Better still, don't use Strings and chars at all.

Comment: Thanks, yes there are other methods to get each digit of a number. But, I am curious because I stumbled upon this issue. I got confused because if I print the value using System.out.println(num.charAt(i)); or debug it, it prints and shows the int value instead of ascii.

Comment: You're printing out the char, but in the if block you're using it as an int.

Comment: Try `System.out.println((int) num.charAt(i));`

Comment: Shoot, just do `System.out.println((int)'1');`

Comment: Then: `System.out.println((int) Character.getNumericValue('1'));`

Comment: What exactly does `count` represent, by the way?

Comment: count represents the number of digits in the given number which can divide it number without a remainder

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows:

```
        if (n % Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i))) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
```

As you can see [Integer.valueOf(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)

> Returns an Integer object holding the value of the specified String.

while you are passing in a `Character`.